# how to store url image in cache memory then display in imageview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I directly open URL image in Imageview  but i want to store the images in cache memory for future reference...  help me to solve my problem..

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what code have you wrote till now (for saving image)? Post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which uses image caching...

This library provides a category for `UIImageVIew` with support for remote images coming from the web.

It provides:

An `UIImageView` category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework

An asynchronous image downloader

An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling

A background image decompression

A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times

A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again

A guarantee that main thread will never be blocked

Performances!
Use GCD and ARC

Comment: any thing like this for mac osx

Comment: Try also SmartStorage(https://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage). It automatically stores UIImage/NSData on disk or in memory. It's smart.

Answer (score 0):

It's a classic problem in iOS development, I write a class [OnlineImageView](https://github.com/siqin/OnlineImageView) before, which is using NSOperationQueue -- Now GCD maybe better.

You wanna access an online image:

1. First, you try to hit the image (with the key, maybe url) in the
   memory cache, but missed.
2. Second, you try to find the image in the disk, missed again.
3. Then, you should download the online image asynchronously, using GCD
   or some other methods.
4. When the image is downloaded successfully, show it in the
   UIImageView, and cache it in the memory, write it down to the disk
   for future use.

Some sample code :

```
- (void)downloadImage:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    /* HOWTO: Prevent Downloading the same url many times */
    /* Keep the download task one by one ? */

    NSString *url = [info objectForKey:@"url"];
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];

    if (image) {
        id theDelegate = [info objectForKey:@"delegate"];
        if ([theDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageDownloader:didFinishWithImage:)]) {
            [theDelegate imageDownloader:self didFinishWithImage:image];
        }

        [cacheQueue cacheImage:image withKey:url];
    } else {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Failed to download : %@\n", url);
#endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) . its best and easy for image data caching.