# UITableViewCell Default Image Blinks While It Lazily Load Images From Web Service

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

In my tableview, i am downloading images from a web service. I want the default image to be set in the image container while it grabs the images from the web service. The asynchronous downloading using GCD is happening in a separate class so it can lazily load the images. Here is the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemsCell";

    ItemsViewCell *cell = (ItemsViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    FeedItem *item = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [item title];

    if (cell.thumbContainer.image != nil) {
        cell.thumbContainer.image = [item thumbnail];

    }
    else
        cell.thumbContainer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultCellImage.png"];

}
```

**The problem that i am facing is that it sets the default image but it keeps on blinking while the images from the web service are loaded. Can any one point out how to fix it?**

**UPDATE:** Here is the method in another class that is downloading the images asynchronously:

```
- (void) downloadThumbnails:(NSURL *)finalUrl
{
    dispatch_group_async(((RSSChannel *)self.parentParserDelegate).imageDownloadGroup, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSMutableData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalUrl];
        [tempData writeToURL:[self cachedFileURLFromFileName:self.thumbFile] atomically:YES];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataSaved" object:nil];

      });
    });
}
```

I saw some related questions on StackOverflow but they didn't help what exactly the problem could be.

**UPDATE:** Kindly do not suggest using SDWebImage or any other image handling library.

Thanks

Comment: If u just want to show images in UITableView and also use caching for smooth scrolling of UITableView refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291960/how-to-store-url-image-in-cache-memory-then-display-in-imageview-in-iphone/15292064#15292064

Comment: Can you verify that your image downloading method is not repeatedly reloading the tableView for each received data?

Comment: @bhuXan i have already completed the caching functionality without any library like SDWebImage so no need of it

Comment: @AJ112 : my experience of using GCD for loading UITableView and specially loading images is not so good, thats why i suggested.

Comment: @Anupdas i have updated the question with the method that is downloading the images, kindly take a look

Comment: I think you are reinventing the whole thing, if it's to load the image asynchronously `SDWebImage` would be better.

Comment: @Anupdas i think my question is different and you people are just suggesting an alternative that i don't want.

Comment: Yes your problem is due to the downloading of image in my opinion. So you if you change that there won't be an issue.

Comment: Even after the image gets downloaded, its not being set. Is it?

Comment: @Mohith NO NOT after the image gets downloaded. Blinks only WHILE its getting downloaded

Comment: I mean, does it set the image after downloading?

Comment: @Mohith yes after the image gets downloaded, it successfully sets and show in the tableview custom cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (cell.thumbContainer.image != nil) {
    cell.thumbContainer.image = [item thumbnail];

}
else
    cell.thumbContainer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultCellImage.png"];
```

For the first time, it sets the default and second time, executes the if stmts. If the image is not downloaded, it sets nothing and third time, sets the default again.

Change it to this, it'l work fine

```
if ([item thumbnail] != nil) {
    cell.thumbContainer.image = [item thumbnail];

}
else
    cell.thumbContainer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultCellImage.png"];
```

Comment: ooo what a stupid little mistake i was doing. Thanks for pointing out. My problem is solved. Marked your answer as the right one.